# Некорректное считывание первой строки из файла(fgets)

Tags: c

Пробую считать данные из файла в динамический массив структур. При считывании первого слова или словосочетания считывание происходит некорректно. В следующих итерациях такой проблемы нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
struct Date 
{
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
};
struct Store 
{
    char category[30];
    char name[30];
    float prise;
    unsigned int amount;
    Date dateOfReceiving;
    Date dateOfRetirement;
};

void ReadTxtFile(Store *arr) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    size_t n;
    long pos;
    if ((fp = fopen("DataBase.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File not found. Create new file or open another file type in main menu.\n");
    }
    else {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        pos = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);
        for (int i = count; !feof(fp) && pos; i++) {
            n = count + 1;
            arr = (Store*)realloc(arr, n);

            fgets(arr[i].category, 14, fp);
            fgets(arr[i].name, 24, fp);
            fscanf(fp, "%f %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &arr[i].prise, &arr[i].amount, &arr[i].dateOfReceiving.Year, &arr[i].dateOfReceiving.Month,&arr[i].dateOfReceiving.Day, &arr[i].dateOfRetirement.Year, &arr[i].dateOfRetirement.Month, &arr[i].dateOfRetirement.Day);
            count++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

[image: Выводит примерно так]

Comment: Поправочка. С считыванием из файла все нормально, проблема с выводом на экран. Я добавил одну запись с клавиатуры, потом добавил записи из файла и проблема была снова с первой записью, которую я вводил с клавиатуры.

Comment: А вывод покажете?

Comment: Ну так удаляйте вопрос тогда. К чему он здесь, если все вышенаписанное - неправда?

Comment: Я уже пробовал, не могу удалить

Answer (score 0):

Тут точно с конца позиция должна быть?

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Может быть нужно SEEK_SET использовать?

Comment: Хорошо, а чему тогда равно count в начале?

Comment: count равно количеству элементов в массиве, на момент возникновения ошибки count = 0

Answer (score 0):

> Может быть нужно SEEK_SET использовать?

Здесь выполняется проверка на наличие информации в файле, после функции fseek() я возвращаю указатель на начало файла функцией rewind(fp).

Answer (score 0):

В С есть функция int fflush(FILE *stream); С ее помощью можно избавиться от лишних символов в потоке. Наример, fflush(stdin) очистит стандартный поток ввода с клавиатуры, а fflush(stdout) - в потоке вывода. Поэкспериментируйте с ней вполне возможно, что передаются лишние символы. Попробуйте, например, добавить fflush(fp) или fflush(stdin) перед считыванием fgets().

Comment: В стандартной билиотеке С функция `fflush` применима только к выходным потокам. Никакого `fflush(stdin)` не допускается.